# Do i really need to study monstrously long intel manual?

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel

I want to be an OS developer. I can say I am a bit comfortable after i read few tutorial on x86 assembly.
But I see a lot detailed in intel manual, does an OS developer really need to study whole manual for its architecture.

1. Is there any alternative ?
2. Will I miss something important if only reading short tutorial rather than manual of architecture

Comment: This is probably off topic for cs.SE, but the short answer is "no". Understand the part you need at any given time. Volume 3, the System Programming Guide, is the part you want, and it's organised well enough that you can read just the bit you need at any given time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to develop an operating system, you have responsibility for things that most developers don't care about. For example, how to make virtual memory work. How to switch from process A to process B without B being able to access any information from process A, and so on. And everything you do must be 100% reliable, not 99.999999%.

You will need deep knowledge of the processor architecture, so you can avoid situations where the same algorithm would work fine on one Intel processor but not on an ARM processor, or an AMD processor, or a different model of Intel processor, or vice versa. You find that knowledge in the Intel manuals.

But starting at page 1 and reading to the end is not the right approach. I'd do one pass skimming through it so that you know what's in the manual, and then leave it on your desk whenever you need it.

Comment: Just as an added comment on some more detail, even just looking at the System Programming guide, many parts are probably irrelevant to your immediate needs. If you're working on a 64-bit OS, for example, then the 16-bit and 32-bit protection mechanisms (e.g. segmentation) are irrelevant. V86 mode is probably obsolete, too. The virtualisation system (VT-x) is relevant, but it can safely wait while you concentrate on paging and the APIC.

Comment: Maybe twenty years ago I had to go through the boot process (still on a 32 bit CPU), and it switched from the most primitive mode to the next higher mode until finally you executed proper "modern" code. Don't know if that is still the case.

Comment: It's less true now. UEFI can drop you straight into 64-bit mode. Be aware that there is no such thing as non-paged 64-bit mode, so UEFI has set up page tables for you that you may want to reclaim at some point.

Comment: Having said that, even if you're supporting BIOS boot and want to do all the mode switching and so forth, there's no shame in cargo culting that part just to get your OS booted and then understanding it fully later.

Answer (score 1):

You don't become an OS developer in a few days, but in years. And most probably you will never become an OS developer for the highly complex x86 architecture at all. This takes whole teams of specialists. Nowadays the major OSes for this platform (Linux & Windows) are there and there's no need for others.

This said, an OS is built with a little of assembly code for the most critical/hardware dependent parts and that takes deep understanding of the most difficult part of the manual related to memory management, interrupt handling, kernel modes and other technicalities. The rest of the code is written in a higher level language such as C and the compiler will take care of the translation to assembly somewhat out of your control. So a great deal of the manual is irrelevant for you.

To develop skills in OS development, you should start by reading theory, and work on projects for simpler architectures or even pure software simulations.

Comment: Don't take it negatively, but if you start with x86, you will hit a brick wall.

Comment: I have to disagree with your second sentence; there are plenty of beginner guides for writing an x86 OS, and they do not need to worry about most of the manual. Now, if you meant a "professional" OS developer, it is correct, but only because there aren't very many and they all work at Microsoft, a dying company. Becoming an open-source OS developer is much more likely, but Linux already exists and you would just be writing a device driver for your new hardware.